# Vim smart tabs inside an if statement

Tags: vim, indentation

I'm using Vim's [SmartTabs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=231) plugin to alingn C code with tabs up to the indentation level, then spaces for alignment after that. It works great for things like

```
void fn(int a,
________int b) {
--->...
```

Tabs are `--->`, spaces are `_`. But it doesn't seem to work so well for cases like

```
--->if(some_variable >
--->--->some_other_variable) {
--->...
```

In the case above, Vim inserts tabs on the second line inside the parentheses. Is there a way I can modify what Vim sees as a continuation line to include cases like this, so I get:

```
--->if(some_variable >
--->___some_other_variable) {
--->...
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I do have a strong opinion: do yourself a favor and never use tabs in your source code again.  Tabs are dead.  Especially in this scenario, where it will only look good to someone with the same tabstop settings as you.

Comment: @JimStewart Eh? Smart tabs is precisely the solution to the problem of different tabstops. The idea is to use tabs up to the indentation level, then spaces to align text. Each indent tab can have as many spaces as it likes, but text alignment needs a precise number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If there's an indentation style that would both allow flexible indentation width according to one's preferences, and consistent alignment, your suggested scheme would be it. Unfortunately, this style requires some basic understanding of the underlying syntax (e.g. whether `some_other_variable` is part of the line-broken conditional (→ Spaces) or a function call within the conditional (→ Tab)), and this makes implementing it difficult.

I'm not aware of any existing Vim plugin. The `'copyindent'` and `'preserveindent'` options help a bit, but essentially you have to explicitly insert the non-indent with <kbd>Space</kbd> yourself (and probably `:set list` to verify).

I don't know about *that other Editor*, but the situation is similar for most other inferior code editors. Without good automatic support, this otherwise elegant style will have a hard time gaining acceptance. I would love to see such a plugin for Vim.

Comment: The plugin seems to have support for lines that end in `,`. I was wondering if that could be extended to lines that end in any operator. Or even lines that end inside open parentheses, maybe. Yes, knowledge of the syntax is necessary, but that's also the case for syntax highlighting, and we manage that fine!